# NSManaged Object Context can't delete object

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsdictionary, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am using Core Data for my iOS Application and in my fetch request, I do a fetch GROUP by some attribute. Because I have to GROUP BY, the result type is NSDictionary and not a managed object.

The table view is working fine, the only problem I am facing in is to delete the row. It won't delete the row and also the context is not deleting the object.

I did some digging and found out that if my result type is a managed object, then the context can delete the object and the table view row gets deleted but then the GROUP BY functionality is lost as it only works when result type is an NSDictionary object.

Any help would be appreciated.

That's the FETCH REQUEST Method  (EDITED)

```
NSError * anyError = nil;

AppDelegate * applicationDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [applicationDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Merchant" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"premiumActName" ascending:YES];

NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[request setSortDescriptors:descriptors];

NSPropertyDescription *accountDesc = [[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"premiumActName"];

NSExpressionDescription* objectIdDesc = [NSExpressionDescription new];
objectIdDesc.name = @"objectID";
objectIdDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

NSArray *propertiesToFetch= @[accountDesc, objectIdDesc];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:propertiesToFetch];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:accountDesc, nil]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

NSArray *distinctResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&anyError];

NSLog(@"function=%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

NSLog(@" result =%@", distinctResults);

if(!_fetchedResultsController)
{
    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
}

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

if(![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&anyError])
{
    NSLog(@" Error =%@", anyError);
}

if (![context save:&anyError])
{
    // Handle the error.
}
```

That's the table view deletion row method  (EDITED)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate *applicationDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [applicationDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSDictionary * dictionary = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSManagedObjectID * iod = [dictionary objectForKey:@"objectID"];

NSManagedObject * object = [context objectWithID:iod];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{             
    [context deleteObject:object];

    // Commit the change.
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", error);
    }
}

    [self.membersTblView reloadData];
}
```

This doesn't delete the object and the table view row too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
NSManagedObject * object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

does not really return a managed object but a dictionary, therefore `[context deleteObject:object]` does not work.

The following could work:

- Add `"objectID"` to the `propertiesToFetch`.
- To delete an object:

  ```
  NSDictionary *dict = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSManagedObjectID *oid = [dict objectForKey:@"objectId"];
  NSManagedObject *object = [context objectWithID:oid];
  [context deleteObject:object];
  [context save:&error];
  ```

Since a fetched results controller with dictionary result type does *not update automatically*, you have also to call:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[self.membersTblView reloadData];
```

again.

Comment: @AngadManchanda: Can you verify that `oid` is a managed object id and that `object` is a managed object?

Comment: It actually worked behind the scenes as in, when I press delete, it does nothing, when I do view will appear or view did load (re launch the app), I see that the row is deleted. So am I missing some line of code?

Comment: @AngadManchanda: You also have to call performFetch again, see my update answer.

Comment: You were right. That did the trick. Seems I have to read apple docs in detail.